# EJB 3.0 TimerService - Run timer on 1st day of every month

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, timeout, ejb-3.0

In EJB 3.0 `TimerService.createTimer(initialDuration, intervalDuration, TimerID)` method is accepting only `initialDuration` and `intervalDuration` arguments.

The problem is I want to run timer on 1st of every month and I can not set my timer using cron expression like in EJB 3.1 `TimerService`.
Some workaround is like run on daily base and check the date inside `@Timeout` method if its '1st of month' but that is not appropriate way.

I went through many example/tutorials online but no luck. Is there any other way to implement this scenario?

Comment: I think you just answered yourself. Running each day and checking the date is a pretty good workaround, and it costs nothing.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following approaches:

- In the `@Timeout` method use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to calculate the next point-in-time. So every timer schedules the next call in its `@Timeout` method . This has the advantage that you are able to build an admin dialog that provides an overview of the scheduled timers in the system which you can't do if you just run the timer daily. I used this to implement a fairly complex, user-configurable timer configuration (Outlook style, i.e. something like "run this every two months on the third at 9:00 AM). Even with JodaTime, I ended up writing a lot of code, though. However, in your case it shouldn't be that complicated. Basically like

> `timerService.createTimer( new DateTime( System.currentTimeMillis()).plusMonths(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate(), null );`

- Abandon TimerService and use [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) directly for scheduling. Then you can feed cron expressions directly into the API. Quartz generally integrates nicely with Java EE, even in complex clustered environments.

Answer (score 2):

```
    try {
        Scheduler scheduler;
        scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        JobDetail job = new JobDetail("job name", "job group", (your class which will implement job interface).class);
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("trigger name", "trigger group", "0 0 0 1 * ?");
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Use above code it will run timer at 1st of every month.

Comment: Did you forget to mention that your snippet uses Quartz or were you assuming that everybody would recognize that immediately from the class names?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. Yes I am using Quartz.